# Shared host permission for notification using WCF Restful with PushSharp

Tags: wcf, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, shared-hosting, pushsharp

I'm trying to send a push notification through WCF Restful web service to iOS using PushSharp. When I deploy my codes to the shared host, I get the following error.

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'Request for the permission of type System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.'. See server logs for more details.

I'm sure my certificate file and password is OK because I can send notification in localhost. 
I think the reason of that error is the trust level. However, I cannot change my trust level to medium on web.config file, the host does not allow that.

How can I give the necessary permission?